# How to enable/disable sections in Pie chart in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to enable/disable sections in a pie chart as Highcharts allow for bar charts,ie in this [Bar Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic), I can enable/disable `Year1800,year1900 and year 2008`  I want something similar in pie chart. How can I do it?

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUXgk/). Moreover, names are also not being shown, ie this area of pie chart belongs to which name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are talking about highchart legends. You can use

for enable

```
legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
```

for disable

```
legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
```

This link will help you

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/enabled-false/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend